# setState не обновляет поля объекта

Tags: reactjs, setstate

вопрос почему в данном случае setState не обновляет объект field?

```html
this.setState(function (state) {
      let newFields = {...state.fields, [fieldName]: null}
      console.log(newFields); // возвращает объект с полем [fieldName]: null
      return {fields: newFields}
  }, () => console.log(this.state.fields)) // исходный объект
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  let fields = Object.assign({}, prevState.fields)
  fields.fieldName = null
  return { fields }
})
```

Либо используя синтаксис `ES6`

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    fields: {                   
        ...prevState.fields,    
        fieldName: null 
    }
}))
```

Comment: Да, я тоже делал так, однако на выходе получаю исходный объект

Comment: Вы мой код пробовали?

Comment: Да, оба метода, ощущение что объект не был присвоен

Comment: А без квадратных скобок?

Comment: Тоже, я выводил сам объект, непосредственно перед присвоением - он правильный, закралась мысль, что есть какой нибудь didUpdate который перетирает изменения

Comment: А реакт дев тулз что показывает?

Comment: Благодарю, проблема была в легаси в затирании в didUpdate